# Redshift - Adding a column, do we have to change our previous CSVs to include it?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I currently have a redshift table in our database that has 10 columns, and I want to add another.  It's trivial to do an alter table to do this.

My question - When I do this, will all my old CSV files fail to insert into redshift (via COPY from S3) given they won't have this new column?

I was hoping the columns would just be NULL vs. it failing on import, but I haven't seen any documentation on this.

Ideally I wish I could specify the actual column name in the header row of the CSV, but I haven't seen if that is possible anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FILLRECORD in COPY command does that: 'Allows data files to be loaded when contiguous columns are missing at the end of some of the records'.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like we just should NEVER drop a column then.